# Redstone torch on a block that is powered directly by another torch doesn't turn off?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

As far as I understood, if you power the block that a redstone torch is on, that redstone torch turns off. But as the question title states, if I power the block directly with another redstone torch, the former redstone torch does not turn off.

Why this is the case? For clarity, here is a screenshot:

[image: redstone torch directly next to a redstone torch on a block]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You aren't actually powering the raised block in this instance, because... reasons.  That block is receiving power from the torch (and would do something if it were a redstone device), but you're not powering it, which sounds strange and contradictory, but that's the best I can explain it.  More critically, you're not transmitting power to the block the second redstone torch is in, as the block it's on is only weakly powered, and thus can't power adjacent blocks.

So in order to power the block, you need to feed a line of powered redstone into it, point a comparator or repeater into it and power that, or place a torch *under* it, like so:

[image: Uncommon not gates]

although your basic not gate (which is what I think you're mainly interested in) is like so:

[image: Basic not gate]

Note that the second torch is on the side of the raised block.  This is important.

Comment: I know it's hard to code, but redstone is the most difficult thing to use since ever

Comment: Ov, thank you very much. Actually, now I see my mistake. It is, redstone torch powers the block that it is in (that is, the empty place which it exist) and the block that is directly above it. The levered block in my example is just a "switched on" block, according to minecraft101.net's jargon. Thanks again.